# Multiple apps for different organizations using single codebase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have single codebase/project & I need to release multiple apps to production for multiple organizations(Code always will be the same) just by changing few things below:

1. App icons, splash screen icons
2. Package name, app name
3. Google-service.json file(As apps using firebase push notifications)

**How can I do it in more efficient way** so that I not need to modify everything in a single project.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Add product flavors to your app using Build -> edit flavors

Or add like this in build.gradle file.

```
productFlavors {
    APP1 {
        applicationId 'example.com.app1'
        versionCode 3
        versionName '3.0.0'
        buildConfigField "com.jujama.utils.BuildType", "BUILDTYPE", "example.com.utils.BuildType.APP1"
    }
    APP2 {
        applicationId 'example.com.app2'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        buildConfigField "com.jujama.utils.BuildType", "BUILDTYPE", "example.com.utils.BuildType.APP2"
    }
```

}

Multiple app resources can be managed in separate directories with same file names

please check https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
https://medium.com/@iammert/android-product-flavors-1ef276b2bbc1 for reference

Answer (score 1):

You can modularise your code.

You can add Android Library module for your codebase. You can have your Activity, extendable-style, in this module.

Then, you can have multiple Phone & Tablet app modules (yes, in the same project and use the same library module). This Android App module is basically just another application that you have using the same codebase.

It has it's own `AndroidManifest.xml`, so you can edit the application name, icon, and description. Even it's own unique Activity or dependency.

Please check these links for further information:

1. [Create Android Library module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#CreateLibrary)
2. [Create Android App Module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module)

Comment: If I need 10 instances of my app than how many android lib mod do i need to add?
& where can I put my icons, splacsh screen image, googleservice.json file, so that every time i not need to change it.

Comment: You only need 1 lib module (if other 10 apps have the same codebase). You can put icon, splash image, googleservice.json, styles, resources, etc in EACH app module. Think of those app modules as standalone application but can use the same codebase.

Comment: all app would be using same code except few cosmetics resources as I said above. So I need to have 10 android libs?

Comment: No. Just 1 lib module (filled with whatever activities, logic, fragments, resources). But you need to have 10 app modules. In those 10 app modules, you can have your own `AndroidManifest.xml`, set up launcher Activity, icons, App name, etc.

Comment: ohk let me give a try.