# Starting app from other app's entry point android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have xamarin.android project Client1 & 1 CommonApp project(within the same solution) which have all common code. From Client1 project I need to start CommonApp, my code to do so in Client1 app

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1).Click += delegate {

            //Starting CommonApp project
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(CommonApp.MainActivity)));
        };
    }
}
```

Below 1 is CommonApp MainActivity where **debugger point going** but not starting new activity but the same activity getting added in backstack when i am pressing physical back button it is getting removed.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //This is CommonApp
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
}
```

CommonApp activity_main have

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="This is CommonApp">
</TextView>
```

**Description**: I have I solution with 2 android app. 1 CommonApp & 2nd Client1. Cleint1 is startup projet having .dll of type CommonApp. From Cleint1 app I am starting CommonApp by importing CommonApp namespace. I can have many project Client1, Client2, Client3...etc with their own icons, app name, splash screen & google-service.json. When I set Client2 on startup it becomes Client2 project & all common code available in CommonApp.

**Requirement**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907812/multiple-apps-for-different-organizations-using-single-codebase/50909338?noredirect=1#comment88819729_50909338)

Output screenshot
[image]

App Log

[Log](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoU8wqJTZgnPqxFgaHGQcKcLfxPG)

Updated screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What are you getting in logs?

Comment: Vic, I have attached log link. check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the CommonApp Activity is actually started (as shown by the debugger) but it doesn't use the correct layout file. Both `MainActivity`s (the one from CommonApp and the one from Client1) use a layout named `activity_main`. So both projects contain a `activity_main.xml` file and it seems that one (from Client1 project) overwrite the other.

There is no namespace for resources, you need to rename the layouts (and any other resources that you want to remain distinct) to avoid the collision. You could add a prefix, e.g. `common_activity_main` and `client_activity_main`

*Edited (additional info from the comments)* :

The project containing the common part should be an *Android Class Library*, not an *Android App*. Otherwise it seems to work (no build error) but the layout file are not present in the APK.

Comment: You now have different Activity names  with different layout names and it does not work ? What happens ?

Comment: Yeah I have different activity names & different xaml file names still same behavior I mean not working. First comment was miss print.

Comment: You can see wit the the debuger that `OnCreate()` from CommonMainActivity is called and use `SetContentView()` with something like 'common_activity_main' and it still show the client1 appearance ?

Comment: `MainActivityCommon` calling, debugger coming & setting `SetContentView(CommonApp.Resource.Layout.activity_main_common);` still not working. See updated screenshot. This is very simple workaround, you can give a try if you don't mind :)

Comment: did you clean / rebuild the whole solution ? maybe a bit stupid but in my experience Xamarin sometimes miss resources changes

Comment: Clean, rebuild, build, restart VS, deleting bin obj folders from both projects, re-adding dll file nothing worked.

Comment: So it seems I missed something, sorry

Comment: what type of project is CommonApp ? it should be an *Android Class Library*, not an *Android App*

Comment: Both are same pure android app. Not library.

Comment: A made a few tests, it works if the common project is a class library, not if it is an app

Comment: The simplest way to convert is  1) exit Visual Studio, 2) in the CommonApp csproj : change <AndroidApplication> to False, 3) restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your common app is installed are not. if already installed you can try this

```
 Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("Com.CommonAPP.CommonAPP");
 if (intent != null)
 {
    StartActivity(intent);
 }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Its not about installing common app. That single app itself containing CommonApp.

Comment: The single solution may contains many project. you could not start another app(eg:commonApp) without installation.

Comment: Single solution can have many project but every project have only CommonApp, so at a time only 1 app setting as startup & stating commonApp.